# Hawtio port conflict issue

Tags: java, mule, jbossfuse, hawtio

I am trying to execute the Hawtio-1.5.jar in Linux environment.  When I am running the executable, it says port is already in use. Can you suggest how to change the port number in Hawtio jar file to resolve this issue?  I cannot change the port number of 8080 which is already using by other my service.

Error logs:

```
[main] INFO org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext - hawtio at http://0.0.0.0:8080/hawtio
[main] WARN org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle - FAILED SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8080: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector.open(SelectChannelConnector.java:187)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector.doStart(AbstractConnector.java:316)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector.doStart(SelectChannelConnector.java:265)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:293)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
    at io.hawt.embedded.Main.run(Main.java:122)
    at io.hawt.embedded.Main.run(Main.java:72)
    at io.hawt.app.App.main(App.java:101)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the port number by `--port` option:

```
java -jar hawtio-app-1.5.2.jar --port 8090
```

See https://hawt.io/docs/get-started/#running-an-executable-jar for more info.

Comment: Yes, this helps.. Thanks a lot.